# Are there any recycled maps from old games in either CoD: Ghosts or Battlefield 4's Season Passes?

Tags: battlefield-3, battlefield-4, call-of-duty-ghosts

Just want to ask about Call of Duty: Ghosts and Battlefield 4 season passes. I had some bad experiences with CoD: Black Ops 2 Season Pass because of the recycled maps from old games, and I want to know if BF3 and CoD: Ghosts have some recycled maps from old BF/CoD games?

Comment: This needs to be two questions.

Comment: IW completely changed the flow and style of maps in CoD: Ghosts, whilst I can't confirm that no maps will make a return, it would be strange if they reverted back to the 3-lane map layout for some DLC. Wish they would bring the 3-lane layout back though :)

Comment: @melnajjar This question has been closed as 'too broad'. Consider asking two separate questions, one for CoD Ghosts and another one for BF4.

Comment: They have revived one older-COD map in the new COD:Ghosts DLC called 'Ignition' I think (can't check as I'm not on my Xbox ATM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Battlefield 3 had four of the most popular maps brought back from Battlefield 2 in Back to Karkand DLC. (Gulf of Oman, Strike at Karkand, Sharqi Peninsula and Wake Island). These maps were edited to fit the destructible environment (which did not exist back in BF2) and they gained a lot more detail.

Battlefield 4's Second Assault DLC contains four of the most popular maps from Battlefield 3. (Caspian Border, Gulf of Oman, Operation Firestorm and Operation Métro).

Comment: It's possible in the China Rising DLC we could see maps from BF2 such as Fushe Pass.

Comment: @tombull89 possible, but CR is still unreleased. I'll keep an eye on it, though.

Comment: for me I'm new BF and you know CoDBO2 has too many recycled maps from CoDBO and it was not fun